# Disable telephone number detection in a WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I am having a problem where in my `WebView` I display Terms and Conditions with HTML tags, the catch is that I don't need to detect phone number because it does even it's not really a phone number. For instance, `1990-1991` is detected as phone number where it shouldn't have. How do I disable this?

Comment: Did you found the solution yet?
I’m still need it, and even migrated from UIWebView to WKWebView, and still looking for this solution